# Is there a way to change the font size of the bounding box in Tensorflow Object Detection?

Tags: tensorflow, fonts, label, object-detection, bounding-box

I am running the TF model on Windows 10 Home and using Jupyter Notebook (more specificaly, I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U). The model detects fine but the font is sometimes very small and hard to read.
[Very small.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WhWi.png)

I have searched online for results and have tried to edit the `visualization_utils.py` file and change the font size there:

```
  try:
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 150)
  except IOError:
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
```

Unfortunately, it did not help. I have also tried to add the specific path to the code:

```
  try:
    font = ImageFont.truetype('C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial\arial.ttf', 150)
  except IOError:
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
```

But that didn't help either. Would love if someone was able to give some guidance to this issue!